# Forms in HTML table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I made the HTML table where the last row contains form for inserting information in the row. They are working, however, whenether I start typing in them, the website highlights the form slightly higher then the actual form. Here is the screenshot of the problem:

[image: screenshot of problem]

Here is the code for the bottom row:

```
...
<tr id="new_row">
        <td>New ID will be given automatically</td>
        <td><input  type="text" id="new_Train_company" v placeholder="Company name"></td>
        <td><input  type="text" id="new_Destination" placeholder="Destination"></td>
        <td><input  type="time" id="new_time"></td>
        <td>
                <select id="new_platform">
                  <option value = '1'>1</option >
                  <option value = '2'>2</option >
                  <option value = '3'>3</option >
                  <option value = '4'>4</option >
                </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="date" id="new_date" ></td>
        <td><input type="button" id="insert_row" value="Insert Row" onclick="insert_row();"></td>
    </tr>
```

And here is the style for the table:

```
.table {

    width: 1000px;
    margin-top: 3%;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    top: 20%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
.table th {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #4CAF50;
}
.table td{
    align-items: center;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000000;
}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is due to your `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` remove this and work with negative margins and you should be fine.

transform keeps the original bounding boxes so everything shifts.

Comment: I've removed it, but it didn't solve the problem. What margin values you suggest to put there?

Comment: what browser are you on?

Comment: I am working on Chrome but ideally I want it to work on Firefox and Safari as well

Comment: I mocked up this codepen https://codepen.io/simplySam/pen/wqqqMv are you  able to recreate it in there?

Comment: I've put there the whole code for the table. Btw as you can see there when adding the new row, the table expands towards the top, how to make it expands toward the botttom?

Comment: can you share the link please? :)

Comment: https://codepen.io/simplySam/pen/qXXXjM for me this works fine! (removed the transform so it wouldn't jump up)